# How to save several arrays automatically passed by an excel to save in the bank using PHP, codeiginter and Spreadsheet?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm making an application to save an excel in xlsx with more than 5 thousand lines in SLQ Serve. I found the spreadsheet and codeiginter library but it happens that I need to save the amount of arrays automatically!

Home_model.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home_model extends CI_Model{

  public function __construct()  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function insert_batch($dataSalva = 0) {

    $totalarray = ''; // I need to get the amount of the array here automatically  

    if ($dataSalva != '') {

      for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalarray; $i++) {

        // if($i > $totalarray){

        // }

        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
          
          $this->db->insert('chargeback_excel', $dataSalva[$i]); 
        }

      };

      if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      } 

    }


  }
}
```

Comment: CodeIgniter have insert_batch method, by using that, you can insert many records once.

Comment: Also, your code is not perfect to understand your need. You are checking affected_rows before inserting anything. It will false at first time only and will never go beyond.